# Put my fillRect in the foreground

Tags: canvas, html5-canvas

I would like to realize a little chart in html5 canvas but my cursor (the pink thing) is not in the foreground.

[image]

```
var canvas = document.getElementById("quantity"); 
var context = canvas.getContext("2d");

context.translate(0, 0);
context.beginPath();                

context.fillStyle="#777";
context.fillRect(5, 10, 35, 30);

context.lineWidth="5";
context.strokeStyle="#777";    
context.rect(5, 10, 90, 30);

context.fillStyle="#b74e95";
context.fillRect(canvas.width/2, 0, 10, 50);
context.stroke();
```

Comment: the last context.stroke() must come after context.rect(5, 10, 90, 30); and not at the end

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below is the changed code, with some mistakes corrects.

```
var canvas = document.getElementById("quantity"); 
var context = canvas.getContext("2d");

context.translate(0, 0);

context.fillStyle="#777";
context.fillRect(5, 10, 35, 30);

context.beginPath();
context.lineWidth="5";
context.strokeStyle="#777";    
context.rect(5, 10, 90, 30);
context.stroke();

context.fillStyle="#b74e95";
context.fillRect(canvas.width/2, 0, 10, 50);
```